# How to Create base64_encode in Login using JSP

Tags: jsp

How do I write this in JSP?

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$resultFilms = $conn->prepare("select * from users where username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
$resultFilms->execute();

$row1 = $resultFilms->fetch();

$privateKey = $row1['pass_key'];
$iv  = $row1['iv'];

$passwordenc =base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $privateKey, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

Answer (score 1):

since you are using jsp just use scripter and write it in java like this:

```java
<%
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

        String message = "Anything"
        System.out.println("Actual message: " + message);

        // Encoding string
        String encodedMessage = encoder.encodeToString(message.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encoded string: "+encodedMessage);

        // Decoding string
        String decodedMessage = new String(decoder.decode(encodedMessage));
        System.out.println("Decoded string: "+decodedMessage);
%>
```

Above code shown how to use base64 encoder and decoder. You can refer this.